# How to find a tree inside a tree in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, recursion, ecmascript-6

let say i have a tree in javascript

```
a1 
--b
----c1
a2
--b2
--b3
----c2
```

and if i wanted to find c2, it should return a2->b3->c2

Lets say my json looked like this?

```
treeFamily = {
            name : "Parent",
            children: [{
                name : "Child1",
                children: [{
                    name : "Grandchild1",
                    children: []
                },{
                    name : "Grandchild2",
                    children: []
                },{
                    name : "Grandchild3",
                    children: []
                }]
            }, {
                name: "Child2",
                children: []
            }]
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the nested children have the wanted key/value. Then take the `name` and hand over the result to the outer call.

```js
function findPath(array, target) {
    var path;
    array.some(({ name, children }) => {
        var temp;
        if (name === target) {
            path = [name];
            return true;
        }
        if (temp = findPath(children, target)) {
            path = [name, ...temp];
            return true;
        }
    });
    return path;
}

var treeFamily = { name: "Parent", children: [{ name: "Child1", children: [{ name: "Grandchild1", children: [] }, { name: "Grandchild2", children: [] }, { name: "Grandchild3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Child2", children: [] }] };

console.log(findPath([treeFamily], 'Grandchild2'));
console.log(findPath([treeFamily], 'foo'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to search the children by calling the function recursively. If the target is found, the name is returned, and combined with the previous names. If not, the function will return `undefined`. Alternatively, you can return an empty array.

```js
const findPath = (targetName, { name, children }) => {
  if(name === targetName) return [name];
  
  for(const child of children) {
    const result = findPath(targetName, child);
    if(result) return [name, ...result];
  }
  
  // if child not found implicitly return undefined or return [] to get an empty array
};

const treeFamily = { name: "Parent", children: [{ name: "Child1", children: [{ name: "Grandchild1", children: [] }, { name: "Grandchild2", children: [] }, { name: "Grandchild3", children: [] }] }, { name: "Child2", children: [] }] };

console.log(findPath('Child2', treeFamily));
console.log(findPath('Grandchild3', treeFamily));
console.log(findPath('Grandchild400', treeFamily));
```

Comment: Thank you. I blocked for a few hours to adapt your algorithm in my project. I used an array.ForEach (...) loop but still got 'undefined' again but using your 'for' loop my result is correct. maybe it could help someone.